# Very keen to offer?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I read the following sentence from a grammar book and I got confused:

"The company is very keen to offer a position to you and another candidate."

What does this sentence mean? I have two options:

1. The company will offer two positions. One for you, one for other candidate.
2. The company is still in decision process. Only one of you will be offered a position.

Which one is correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, "The company is "eager/interested" to offer a position to you and another candidate."

[Keen - Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keen)

Comment: So there are two positions will be possiblely offered, right?

Comment: @JumpJump, Yes, you are right about it.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence does state 'a position', implying there is only one job.  However the sentence as a whole means that there is a position both for you and for another candidate.  The key word being 'and' - if it was 'or' then your second option would be true.

Answer (score 0):

The company is very happy and excited to offer a position to you and the other candidate as well.  Keen = happy and excited and eager.